# SeekBar - NinePatchDrawable cannot be cast to LayerDrawable

Tags: java, android

I am going to change color of the SeekBar with below code.

```
public void setColor(SeekBar view, Integer color) {
    LayerDrawable drawable = (LayerDrawable) view.getProgressDrawable().getCurrent();

    Drawable progress = drawable.findDrawableByLayerId(android.R.id.progress);

    progress.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
}
```

**Some of devices ran the code with no error**. But some of devices will return java.lang.ClassCastException android.graphics.drawable.NinePatchDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.

Is anyone have workaround for this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use your custom png for this purpose and implement it like this:

**drawable/color_progress.xml**

```
<item
    android:id="@android:id/background"
    android:drawable="@drawable/static_slider"/>
<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <scale
        android:drawable="@drawable/static_slider"
        android:scaleWidth="100%" />
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <scale
        android:drawable="@drawable/active_slider"
        android:scaleWidth="100%" />
</item>
```

and use inside your seekbar like this

```
 <SeekBar
  ......
 android:progressDrawable="@drawable/color_progress" />
```

static_slider and active_slider are different PNGs for empty and filled state.
Hope this helps.